# Error: Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula

Tags: workflow, formula

I have trying to build a formulae in workflow on the Final result which should show error message if the the prior value of Final Result is either (ACCEPTED,Need More Information-Incorrect Patient/Insurance Information,Need More Information-Waiting For Fax/Documents/Dx Codes) to REJECTED it show send an email. Final Result is a picklist field.

```
OR(

AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Final_Result__c),"ACCEPTED"),ISPICKVAL(Final_Result__c,"REJECTED")),


AND
(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Final_Result__c),"Need More Information-Incorrect Patient/Insurance Information"),ISPICKVAL(Final_Result__c,"REJECTED")),

AND
(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Final_Result__c),"Need More Information-Waiting For Fax/Documents/Dx Codes"),ISPICKVAL(Final_Result__c,"REJECTED")))
```

I get the error:

> Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you set `Evaluation Criteria` to `created, and any time it's edited`.

You will get this error if you instead select `created` or `created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`. The same holds true for `ISCHANGED`.

See also: [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#PRIORVALUE)

> This function is available only in:
>
> - Assignment rules
> - Validation rules
> - Field updates
> - **Workflow rules if the evaluation criteria is set to `Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited`.**
> - Formula criteria for executing actions in the Process Builder.