# Workflow rule using a picklist value change as trigger

Tags: trigger, email, workflow, formula, picklist

This is my first go round with writing a workflow rule and am struggling to find correct syntax. Our Salespeople who generated a lead (Salesperson__c - a contact lookup field) want to get an email when the Status (Status) of the lead they brought in changes.

So I first tried `Status= ISCHANGED(field)`. No luck, so then I tried `ISCHANGED(Status)`.

Neither worked because it's a picklist I believe.

Do I need to use a `ISPICKVAL` formula? If so, does someone know correct syntax for this?

[image: Lead Status Values]

[image]

My updated formula is:

```
TEXT(Status) != TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status))
```

But it gives this error:

> Error: Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because of your Workflow evaluation criteria

You need it to be: `rule evaluation criteria is set to "Every time a record is created or edited`

@AdrianLarson [already answered this once before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/121843/2602).

Comment: Not the original issue, but good work actually reading the error message! :P

Answer (score 0):

Set your your Workflow evaluation criteria to 'created, and every time it's edited' 
There you can use ISCHANGED(Status) Function Also.
[image: when i change my Workflow evaluation criteria to 'created, and every time it's edited' it works for me]

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. My issue has been solved!